# char * (*name)[2] as a function parameter

Tags: arrays, c, function

I was given a function that I have to fill out and it has these input parameters:

```c
char * replace( const char * text, const char * (*word)[2] )
```

From my understanding, the function should return a string and is given a string in the first parameter.

The second parameter is an array of subarray that each have 2 strings if I'm not mistaken, but what is the meaning of the `*(*name)[2]`, what is the difference between that and `**name[2]` And how would I call this array in the function?

EDIT: How do I **use** this array in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to array decay of functions parameters the function's declaration is equivalent to:

```
char * replace( const char * text, const char * word[][2] )
```

So the second argument must be a 2D array of `const char*`.

```
int main() {
    const char * words[1][2] = { {"hello", "world"} };
    replace("some text", words);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for, thank you

Comment: I suggest you assign the result to something otherwise `replace()` is a noop.

Answer (score 1):

word is a pointer to array 2 of pointer to const char (1 address), while `const char **word2[2]` is an array of 2 pointer to pointer to const char (2 addresses):

```
int main() {
    const char *words[] = { "hello", "world" };
    const char *(*word)[2] = &words;
    const char **word2[2] = {
        &words[0],
        &words[1]
    };
}
```

Your 2nd question, "how to do I call this array", does not make sense.  You use an array (see above) and call a function:

```
char *result = replace("hello world", word);
```